# AlarmManager not working for specific date

Tags: android, service, calendar, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I have been trying to set AlarmManager for Specific date, but it is not working at all! When I  just use the time it works fine.
Here is the code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            String getEventTime = prefs.getString("EventSTime", "");
            String getEventDate = prefs.getString("EventDate", "");
            Toast.makeText(this, getEventTime + " " + getEventDate,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String temp = "", temp2 = "";
            DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            DateFormat dateformatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
            try {
                temp = dateformat.format(dateformat.parse(getEventTime));
                temp2 = dateformatDate.format(dateformatDate
                        .parse(getEventDate));
                Toast.makeText(this, temp + " " + temp2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String getEventTimeSubStringHour = temp.substring(0, 2);
            String getEventTimeSubStringMinute = temp.substring(3, 5);
            String getEventDateSubStringDay = temp2.substring(0, 2);
            String getEventDateSubStringMonth = temp2.substring(3, 5);
            String getEventDateSubStringYear = temp2.substring(6, 10);
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    getEventTimeSubStringHour + " "
                            + getEventTimeSubStringMinute + " "
                            + getEventDateSubStringDay + " "
                            + getEventDateSubStringMonth + " "
                            + getEventDateSubStringYear, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            hourOfDay = Integer.parseInt(getEventTimeSubStringHour);
            minute = Integer.parseInt(getEventTimeSubStringMinute);
            day = Integer.parseInt(getEventDateSubStringDay);
            month = Integer.parseInt(getEventDateSubStringMonth);
            year = Integer.parseInt(getEventDateSubStringYear);
            int second = 0;
//          calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
//          calendar.clear();
            //calendar.set(year, month, day);
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);


            Intent intent = new Intent(MessageService.this,
                    ServiceManager.class);
            PendingIntent callToServiceManager = PendingIntent.getService(
                    MessageService.this, 2, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmToCallServiceManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmToCallServiceManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), callToServiceManager);
```

Even after using `calendar.set(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute, second)` nothing is happening. 
Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and it's so annoying. I notice on my system if I remove anything to do with YEAR and MONTH that it works.

Comment: It turns out I was storing June as the month 6. Actually it should be stored aS 5, months are counted from 0.

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe oh I should try it then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Eugen for guiding me.
It turn out to be the problem of Value, Indeed I was storing June as 7th Month instead of 6th. I was adding 1 to the month and it was making problem. Now I have fixed it and it is working fine now.